# Unlock Users PC without Password Will a AD reset work?

Tags: windows, active-directory

We had a user leave the business but left their computer logged in if I reset their password in AD would I be able to unlock their account?

If that doesn't work what can I do?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean, unlock their workstation. If the workstation is on the network, the answer is yes.

Comment: `If that doesn't work what can I do?` - Power cycle the workstation and log in as an Administrator.

Comment: Problem was that we needed to get to unsaved info

Comment: Also note that resetting user's password with user still logged on with the old password can lead to user's account being locked in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workstation caches the credentials of the user when off the network.  So changing them in the directory won't help.  There are a few things you can do:

1. @Nixphoe is correct, this machine (if on a domain) needs to be on the network.
2. You can use Domain Admin credentials to log into the machine and grab whatever data you are after. (if a domain admin has logged into the machine in the past and the credentials have been cached)
3. You could wipe the local admin password with a utility.

In short if you are on the local network, or VPN, you are good to go.

Comment: As I recall, if the password is wrong on the workstation, it then asks the domain controller.